# Why can't I multiply 16 by 2?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tags

I'm trying to program a 2048 game in C# using WinForms, and I've just finished setting up the code to merge numbers. 2 can merge into 4, 4 can merge into 8, 8 can merge into 16, and 32 can merge into 64. But 16 can't merge into 32??? All of the files are identical except for the image and name.
[All of the files in their folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAn38.png)

This code checks if two of the same number are trying to occupy the same space, and should merge them into one cell, which works for everything but 16 into 32. It just gets the tag of the image, multiplies it by 2, and sets that as the new tag and file path.

```
else if ((imageList[a, b].Tag == imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag) && imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() != "0")
{
    imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag = (int.Parse(imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() ?? string. Empty) * 2).To String();
    imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Image = Image.FromFile(imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag.ToString() + ".jpg");

    imageList[a, b].Image = null;
    imageList[a, b].Tag = "0";

    move = true;
}
```

To view the tag, which holds the value of the number as a string, I've used:

```
MessageBox.Show(imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag.ToString());
```

When merging two numbers, it shows me the tag for the new number, including 16, and by manually adding in 32, I can see that they correctly have the tag of 64. I have duplicated every single file to make sure that they're not the issue, and it's still not working.

I've also tried merging 16 separately.

```
else if (imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() == "16")
{
    imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag = "32";
    imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Image = Image.FromFile("32.jpg");

    imageList[a, b].Image = null;
    imageList[a, b].Tag = "0";

    move = true;
}
```

For some reason, this works, but the original multiplication design doesn't.

Here is the full code of a key press for everyone who wants it:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int aChange = 0;
    int bChange = 0;
    bool valid = false;
    if (e.KeyChar.ToString().ToLower() == "a")
    {
        aChange = -1;
        valid = true;
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar.ToString().ToLower() == "d")
    {
        aChange = 1;
        valid = true;
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar.ToString().ToLower() == "w")
    {
        bChange = -1;
        valid = true;
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar.ToString().ToLower() == "s")
    {
        bChange = 1;
        valid = true;
    }


    if (valid == true)
    {
        bool move = true;
        while (move)
        {
            move = false;
            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
                {
                    if (a + aChange > -1 && a + aChange < 4 && b + bChange > -1 && b + bChange < 4)
                    {
                        if (imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() != "0" && imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag.ToString() == "0")
                        {
                            imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag = imageList[a, b].Tag;
                            imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Image = Image.FromFile((imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag.ToString() ?? string.Empty) + ".jpg");

                            imageList[a, b].Image = null;
                            imageList[a, b].Tag = "0";

                            move = true;
               
                        }
                        else if ((imageList[a, b].Tag == imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag) && imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() != "0")
                        {
                            imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag = (int.Parse(imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() ?? string.Empty) * 2).ToString();
                            imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Image = Image.FromFile(imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag.ToString() + ".jpg");

                            imageList[a, b].Image = null;
                            imageList[a, b].Tag = "0";

                            move = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        bool cont = false;
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
            {
                if (imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    cont = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (cont)
        {
            while (cont)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                int x = r.Next(0, 4);
                int y = r.Next(0, 4);
                if (imageList[y, x].Tag.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    imageList[y, x].Image = Image.FromFile("2.jpg");
                    imageList[y, x].Tag = "2";
                    cont = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Game Over!");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the method of creating all 16 picture boxes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PictureBox[,] imageList = new PictureBox[4, 4];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (this.Width > this.Height)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size(this.ClientSize.Height, this.ClientSize.Height);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new Point((this.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (this.ClientSize.Height / 2), 0);
        }
        else
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Width);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new Point(0, (this.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (this.ClientSize.Width / 2));
        }
            
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
            {
                PictureBox newBox = new PictureBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None, SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage, Tag = "0" };
                imageList[a, b] = newBox;
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newBox, a, b);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Yes, that was just a typo, my mistake. The code itself doesn't contain that whitespace.

Comment: Can you post the full code for all your forms?

Comment: What do you mean by all my forms? This program only uses one form and one table layout panel. I could try posting the entire code though?

Comment: @forefie that would help.

Comment: Sidenote: instead of `if (valid == true)` you can omit `== true` or better: ditch the `valid` flag, add a final `else` to the if/else checks before it, that just `return`s and there you go. Less indentation ...

Comment: @Filburt I've tried debugging this for hours, but I haven't found a single reason that every other number except 16 works.

Comment: _" I've tried debugging this for hours, but I haven't found a single reason that every other number except 16 works"_ - Have you written a Unit Test before? Because that's what I'd suggest. Extract the logic into a method. Then write a test for that method.

Comment: I've tried adding in 16 manually, and they merge into 32 fine. But when I do that, I can't merge 32 into 64??? The headache continues.

Comment: @forefie you said you only have a Form and a table layout panel.. but you are using a collection of ImageList, aren't you? how are you declaring it?

Comment: @jarmanso7 I added it to the post

Comment: I am trying to debug it with a version I made but [it looks very ugly](https://imgur.com/rzPDLWa) (The grid is not 4x4). Do you have the full project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem in your code. The problem is in the comparison:

```
imageList[a, b].Tag == imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag
```

This doesn't work as you expect because you are **comparing the Tag properties directly, which point to different instances, instead of comparing their string representation**. Both instances have the string representation "16", but since they are different instances, when you compare them for equality it returns `false`, and then the merge code is not executed.

In order to fix it, in the line:

```
else if ((imageList[a, b].Tag == imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag) && imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() != "0")
```

add `.ToString()` after `.Tag` for this comparison as well:

```
else if ((imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() == imageList[a + aChange, b + bChange].Tag.ToString()) && imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() != "0")
```

> I've also tried merging 16 separately. For some reason, this works, but the original multiplication design doesn't.

It works because you are comparing two strings, `imageList[a, b].Tag.ToString() == "16"`, but if you'd compare the Tag directly against a string literal, `imageList[a, b].Tag == "16"`, it wouldn't work either.

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally works! The headache is over at last.